# okhttp3 throws NetworkOnMainThreadException when loading images asynchronously with glide

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-glide, okhttp, leanback

I'm trying to load images asynchronously into a CardPresenter in Leanback like this.

```
public interface CustomImageModel {  
    String requestCustomUrl(int width, int height);
}

public static class CustomImageModelGrabber implements CustomImageModel {

    public CustomImageModelGrabber() {

    }

    @Override
    public String requestCustomUrl(int width, int height) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient;
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(image_url).build();
        return client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
    }
}

public static class CustomImageUrlLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<CustomImageModel> {  
    public CustomImageUrlLoader(Context context) {
        super( context );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUrl(CustomImageModel model, int width, int height) {
        return model.requestCustomUrl();
    }
}
```

In CardPresenter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {

    CustomImageModel customImageRequest = new CustomImageModelGrabber();

    Glide  
            .with( context )
            .using( new CustomImageUrlLoader( context ) )
            .load( customImageRequest )
            .into( imageView1 );
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. **Only a few images are loaded correctly** into the card presenter, but most of them are not, and the following error is thrown:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
```

It's totally random which work and which don't.

I also tried setting the strict mode in MainActivity.java.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

While this solution loads all images correctly and doesn't throw any `NetworkOnMainThreadException` errors, it comes with huge performance issues. The scrolling becomes slow and laggy, showing me the following message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 182 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Is there any solution to make the images load asynchronously while still maintaining a smooth and good performance?

Comment: I believe this line `client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();` is a synchronous execution of a network request and causes your issue.

Comment: you're right... I used this code because I thought that `BaseGlideUrlLoader` is running on a background-thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was totally wrong. I thought that `BaseGlideUrlLoader` runs on a background-thread, but it doesn't.

So the code to go is the following:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {

    final ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient;
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(image_url).build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);


            String imageFromResponse = responseBody.string();
            // do whatever is needed to get the image (i.e JSON-handling)

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Glide.with(cardView.getContext())
                            .load(imagefromResponse)
                            .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                            .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
                }
            };
        }
    });


}
```